# How to make a 301 redirect of several get requests

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get, request

I've finished a website, now i'm changing old website to new and creating 301 redirects in `.htaccess`.

I have a sitemap containing aroud 100 equal get requests like:

```
?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish
```

In the new website there is no similar request and all this requests must be redirected to a fixed website, lets say `http://myrestaurant.com/menu`

There is a way I can avoid 100+ lines of almost similar httacces lines:

Instead of:

```
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish1 http://myrestaurant.com/menu
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish2 http://myrestaurant.com/menu
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish3 http://myrestaurant.com/menu
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish4 http://myrestaurant.com/menu
```

Make all this in one line or function, something similar to:

```
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu* http://myrestaurant.com/menu
```

**NOTE:** this requests are multilanguage, so I will need more than one rule / redirect:

```
Redirect 301 ?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish3 http://myrestaurant.com/menu
Redirect 301 /ca?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish3 http://myrestaurant.com/ca/menu
Redirect 301 /es?foodmenu=name-of-the-dish3 http://myrestaurant.com/es/menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not match against query strings in redirect directive, try :

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?foodmenu=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}menu? [L,R]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote some typos in my edit... are corrected now... Please check... A question: maybe  `%{REQUEST_URI}menu?` must contain language code?

Comment: Yes, if /ca is in the uri, then  %{REQUEST_URI} will definitely contain it.

Comment: I mean with 2 equal requests but with different URL because contains the language code... how should I modify the condition/rule?

Comment: changing file via ftp must apply changes? or I must restart server??

Comment: No,you dont need to restart server for that because htaccess rules are applied immideatly.

Comment: solved! wordpress rules were causing to not work... I added this first and all seems to be ok thanks!